# Why is the compiler trying to convert char * into char?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, string, struct

I am having trouble instantiating a struct due to the string/`char` array.

Here is my struct:

```
struct Drink {
    char name[10];
    int volume;
    double price;
    int quantity;
};
```

and here is where I am getting the error:

```
void loadDrinksFromFile(const char* filename) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    int count = 0;
    char name[10];
    int volume;
    double price;
    int quantity;

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d %lf %d", name, &volume, &price, &quantity) != EOF) {
        // name is the cause of the error
        machine[count++] = Drink{ name, volume, price, quantity };
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

It says `a value of type char * cannot be used to initialize the entity of type char`.
Why is my code trying to receive a `char` type in the first place?
My struct is expecting `char name[10]` which is an array of `char`s
and I am passing an array of `char`s.
I tried adding `*` and `&`, which I believe does not make sense either, but still it did not work.

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: fixed length array copying never made it into a standard C language.

Answer (score 4):

Because neither C nor C++ support direct assignment of an existing raw array. Both allow to initialize an array with initializer list `{x,y,z...}` or string literals though.

E.g. `int foo[] = {1,2,3};` is ok but `int foo[12]{}; int bar[12]=foo;` is not.

Just use `std::array<T,N>` as it has the desired semantics. Or better `std::string` for char arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to use a compound literal, the syntax looks like a cast followed by an initializer list:

```
machine[count++] = (struct Drink){ name, volume, price, quantity };
```

However, this still won't work because an array can't be used as an initializer.

In this case, you're better off writing to the struct fields directly from `fscanf`.

```
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d %lf %d", machine[count].name, &machine[count].volume, 
                  &machine[count].price, &machine[count].quantity) == 4) {
        count++;
    }
```